# Optimize code for efficiency + quick question

Tags: jquery

This is a simple one for you jQuery gurus here in Stackoverflow.

I have the following jQuery function and I'm wondering if there's a way to optimize the code:

```
$('.dropdown li').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().find('.active').removeClass('active')
    $(this).siblings().find('ul:visible').slideUp();        
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
    $('ul:first',this).slideToggle();       
    $('.arrow-down',this).toggleClass('active');
 });
```

### --------

Quick question as well:

What is the difference between `('.selector' + this)` and `('.selector', this)`? I hope I typed this right.

As you can see I'm quite new to jQ so I need all the help I can get even if I'm asking stupid questions ^_^

Thanks in advance.

Comment: New programmers always worry about efficiency and prematurely optimize. DON"T DO THIS! Write clean maintainable code FIRST, then profile and fix what is slow.

Comment: @Byron: You can write clean, maintainable code but still adopt good, efficient practices as you learn.

Comment: If I had a dime every time someone says something like that when a performance question is asked instead writing a useful answer...

Comment: @Pablo, that is why it is in the comments section. If I had a dime for every time a junior developer wasted time optimizing something like a for loop after a db query...

Comment: @patrick very true. Point taken.

Comment: @Byron: Sheesh, thanks for nothing. At least wanting to prematurely optimize is a good problem to have. Any comments on my second question? :) Tnx to patrick and Pablo.

Comment: Ricardo: I think @Byron meant well. There can be bleeding edge optimizations that can actually get in the way of your coding, especially when you're new. I added an answer to address your second question.

Comment: @Ricardo I'd answer but patrick already handled that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tips:

1 - Seems you're attaching an event handler to many `<li>` elements. Don't do that, use [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead

2 - No need to do $(this) all the time, just do `var $this = $(this);` and use `$this` from now on.

3 - If you're really into speeding this up (I don't see any big performance problems there BTW), drop jQuery and use plain javascript.

Comment: Have not heard or seen the delegate handler before, thanks for pointing it out. The reason I'm using jQuery is because we're already using the framework across the website, and because it's friendlier to use. Gracias por la info.

Answer (score 2):

> *"What is the difference between `('.selector' + this)` and `('.selector', this)`?"*

That will depend on what the value of `this` is.

If you're in a handler, then `this` willl be the element that invoked the handler. As such, this:

```
('.selector' + this)
```

...is pretty much useless, since your selector string will look like:

```
".selector[object HTMLLIElement]"
```

...which isn't a valid selector.

But this one is different:

```
('.selector', this)
```

It makes `this` (your element) the root from which you're performing the query for `.selector`.

It is effectively the same as:

```
$(this).find('.selector');
```

...and in fact, jQuery just flips it around behind the scenes to that form, so you're better of just using `.find()` in the first place since it will be more efficient, and its meaning is a little clearer IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.dropdown li').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('hover').find('.active').removeClass('active')
    .end().find('ul:visible').slideUp();
    $('ul:first',this).slideToggle();       
    $('.arrow-down',this).toggleClass('active');
 });
```

Comment: ShankarSangoli, I tried your code but it didn't work. I see you have everything in one line (which is somewhat what I expected) but the only thing that works is the toggling of the 'hover' class. Guess I'm gonna stick with what I have and improve it with Pablo's suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any js error? I have basically used chaining make sure you have your code proper in place.

Comment: No, no JS error, it just doesn't work, menus don't drop down at all, the only thing I see happening in Firebug is the 'hover' class being injected on the `li`. I also tried adding `.siblings()` (since I don't see it in the code) but it didn't work either. Thanks.

Comment: @Ricardo - There was a missing parenthesis after end, can you please try now I have edited my answer?

Comment: Thanks ShankarSangoli. Unfortunately it didn't quite work as expected. The drop downs are appearing now but there are two problems: 1. When I try to collapse them, they slide back down. 2. If a drop down is already visible/open, it doesn't collapse when another drop down appears. Thanks.

Comment: This is as per the logic in your code you might have to change it as per your requirement. Especially look at $('ul:first',this).slideToggle();